# Which chart type should display following chart? gauge or column?

Tags: highcharts

[image: I want to display chart like below.]

I want to display chart like below.The bar chart start at 0.5(not zero). Positive value shows green color, negative value shows red color. Which chart type can easily do this? Im thinking about bar/column chart, but not sure if they can start from 0.5? Or gauge chart? Can anyone give me an example? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the threshold option to accomplish this, and use the negativeColor property to handle the colors.

```
example:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yPLVP/27/

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.threshold
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.negativeColor

Answer (score 0):

I advice to familiar with boxplot (gauge looks like different) or column with defined color point.

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/box-plot

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.color

Comment: Thanks. For the column chart, can we set its start point not from zero?